# Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier - Higher Order Function that Returns a Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Putting together a simple script to test out a more complex math operation in JavaScript. The goal of the function is to return a function that will add an input by x.

For example:

```
const addByTwo = addByX(2);
addByTwo(1); //should return 3
addByTwo(2); //should return 4
addByTwo(3); //should return 5

const addByThree = addByX(3);
addByThree(1); //should return 4
addByThree(2); //should return 5
```

Here's my function:

```
function addByX (input) {
  function output () {
    return input + 2;
  }
  return output;
}

const addByTwo = addByX(2);
```

Error:
I'm currently getting: *Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier*

Test code:

```
console.log(addByTwo(1));
console.log(addByTwo(2));
```

Comment: Read and post the _full error message_, which should also show the “where” / “context”. If not, try another browser which does.. the posted code appears free of _that_ syntax error.

Comment: This is the full error message afaik and can see generated in my browser Google Chrome (Version 83.0.4103.97).

Comment: Create a fiddle (such as jsfiddle or similar) and post a link here. The code above is visually correct, so two hypothesis are 1) different code is being run locally and there is an error in representation, or 2) there is some invisible character causing problems (a zero-width space could do this). Using a fiddle service will quickly allow others to continue diagnosis and also validated the code in an isolated context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On what line are you getting a SyntaxError? Your definition of `addByX` appears to be incorrect. It should be as follows:

```js
function addByX(x) {
  function output(input) {
    return input + x;
  }
  return output;
}

const addByTwo = addByX(2);
addByTwo(1); //should return 3
addByTwo(2); //should return 4
addByTwo(3); //should return 5

const addByThree = addByX(3);
addByThree(1); //should return 4
addByThree(2); //should return 5

console.log(addByTwo(1));
console.log(addByTwo(2));
```

Comment: For some reason I still get "Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier" when I call either addByTwo with an input of 1 and log the output or addByTwo with an input of 2 and log the output. Where const addByTwo = addByX(2);

Comment: Does not explain the “reported problem”, which may have been incorrectly reported..

Comment: @Codestudio in what environment are you attempting to run this code (e.g. browser, Node, and if a browser what browser)? Does it work if you use `var` instead of `const`?

Comment: The problem is accurately reported. I'm getting this same error running it myself as shown verbatim above. Especially when I addByTwo with an with varying inputs and log the output.

Comment: I'm running the code in browser (Google Chrome). It doesn't work with var nor const.

Comment: @Codestudio are you running it from the Developer Tools Web Console? If you use the "Run code snippet" button above do you see the same errors in the console?

Comment: This works! Turns out there was a small stray "." causing the bug

Answer (score 0):

define your addByX function like this:

```
function addByX (x) {
  return function output (input) {
    return x + input;
  }
}

const addByTwo = addByX(2);
const addOne = addByTwo(1);

console.log(addOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function like this

**Function:**

```
function addByX(fun_name, input)
{
    var add = 0;
    if (fun_name == "Two") add=2;
    else if (fun_name == "Three") add = 3;

    return add + input;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
addByX("Two", 1);
addByX("Three", 1);
```